# Why when I analyse a field in django database in views.py it doesn't react?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm having a bit of a problem. I have a model for an Article:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, default='edited')
    slug = models.BooleanField(null=False, default=False)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True)
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True)
```

I wanted to make it work in a way that only one record can have the slug set to True. So I wrote this in my update view:

```
def updateArticle(request, pk):
    articles = Article.objects.all()
    article = Article.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = ArticleForm(instance=article)
    if request.method == "POST":
        counter = 0
        for i in articles:
            if i.slug:
                counter += 1
        if counter > 1 and article.slug == True:
            for j in articles:
                j.slug = False
        form = ArticleForm(request.POST, instance=article)
        form.save()
        return redirect('/')
    return render(request, 'update_article.html', {
        'article': article,
        'form': form,
    })
```

But it doesn't work :((
I would be very thankful if you could help.

Comment: The `j` is never saved, so `j.slug = False` will indeed not update the database.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to write it so that it saves in the database?

Answer (score 0):

You do not *save* the objects in the `articles` queryset. But nevertheless, you do not need to make it so complicated. You can simply set the `slug` field of all other `article`s to `False` in case `article.slug` is `True`:

```
def updateArticle(request, pk):
    article = Article.objects.get(id=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ArticleForm(request.POST, instance=article)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            if article.slug:
                Article.objects.exclude(pk=article.pk).update(slug=False)
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = ArticleForm(instance=article)
    return render(request, 'update_article.html', {
        'article': article,
        'form': form,
    })
```

This will perform the update at the database level, which is normally more efficient than updating at the Django/Python level.